# How to fill in a lot of data utlizing pandas fillna fast?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have two Dataframes one large one with a lot of missing values and a second one with data to fill the missing data in the first one.

Dataframe examples:

```
In[34]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B1': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 9, 1],'B2':[1, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 6, 1], 'B3':[1, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 7, 1] })
df=df.set_index(['A'])
df2=df2.set_index(['A'])

In[35]:
df

Out[35]: 
   B1  B2  B3
A            
0   1   1   1
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3   8   7   8
4   9   6   7
5   1   1   1

In[36]:
df2

Out[36]: 
   B
A   
1  1
1  0
1  1
2  1
2  0
2  0
```

so what I want to do is fill up df using the data from df2 also taking into account that B1 is not B2 when coming across a second instance in df2.
See below the desired output:

```
In[38]:
df

Out[38]: 
   B1  B2  B3
A            
0   1   1   1
1   1   0   1
2   1   0   0
3   8   7   8
4   9   6   7
5   1   1   1
```

The NaNs in B1, B2 and B3 for 1 and 2 have been filled with the data from df2. 1 0 1 for index 1 and 1 0 0 for index 2. 
See below my inefficient for loop implementation:

```
In[37]:
count=1
seen=[]

for t in range(0, len(df2)):
     if df2.index[t] not in seen:
         count=1
         seen.append(df2.index[t])
     else:
         count=count+1
     tofill=pd.DataFrame(df2.iloc[t]).transpose()
     tofill_dict={"B"+str(count):tofill.B}
     df=df.fillna(value=tofill_dict)
```

This works, however when the dataset gets larger it can take a significant amount of time. So my question is if there is a way to do this faster?
I have heard vectorization could work, how would you implement this? Are there any other ways to do this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you cannot reset index of `df2`.

You can use try [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) - each group is transposing with `T` and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) `df` by values of `df2`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B1': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 9, 1],'B2':[1, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 6, 1], 'B3':[1, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 7, 1] })
df=df.set_index(['A'])
df2=df2.set_index(['A'])

print df
   B1  B2  B3
A            
0   1   1   1
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
3   8   7   8
4   9   6   7
5   1   1   1
print df2
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  0
2  1  1
3  2  1
4  2  0
5  2  0
```

```
df2 = df2.groupby(df2.index).apply(lambda x: x.B.reset_index(drop=True).T)
df2.columns = df.columns
print df2
   B1  B2  B3
A            
1   1   0   1
2   1   0   0    

df = df.fillna(df2)
print df

    B1  B2  B3
A            
0   1   1   1
1   1   0   1
2   1   0   0
3   8   7   8
4   9   6   7
5   1   1   1
```

Maybe if `df = df.fillna(df2)` doesn't work, can be use `df = df.combine_first(df2)`. It depends on index.

Comment: How does it work? I cannot compare it with your solution, because error: `NameError: global name 'toappend' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for your answer jezrael! I fixed the cause of the error, my bad sorry. I have quickly checked, and it works when utilizing `df2 = df2.groupby(df2.index).apply(lambda x: x.B.reset_index(drop=True).T) `instead of `df2 = df2.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.B.reset_index(drop=True).T)`. Need to test on the large dataset when I get home

Comment: ok, you are right, but I thought that you reset index only for this filling. So I want remove this operation. I edit answer.